# How did Michael Scott become regional manager?

Tags: the-office

I mean, Michael Gary Scott is so childish, lame and gets no work done.

He procrastinates all the time, wastes other people's time and does zero productivity per day.

Yet he is the manager, how?

Comment: Promoted to the level of his own incompetence.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm pretty sure this is correct. I haven't seen the show, but I've heard that there are a number of episodes that show us what an excellent salesman he was?

Comment: @DrRDizzle Wikipedia tells us that he is an excellent salesman and that his branch is the highest performing *despite* his incompetence. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Scott_(The_Office)

Comment: @DrRDizzle That's actually one of the main differences between the 2 versions. The US one was obviously going to be longer, so they had to justify Michael keeping his position by occasionally showing him being good at his *actual* job: Making good deals, having a great rapport with clients and running a successful branch. Other than Dwight, he's one of the few people there who actually care about what they do; the rest just wish they were *anywhere* else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He is very childish and at times incompetent, but he can also connect with people in surprising ways.

Recall the episode when he & Andy go on a sales call (*Traveling Salesman*) and the man they speak with has a fishing photo on his desk. Michael strikes up a conversation about how he used to go fishing there as a kid and now he and the client [can't remember his name] have a connection. Naturally Andy ruins things but the important part to remember is that Michael is more than capable of being a people person.

Another great example is the Chili's episode (*The Client*) where Michael breaks down any defenses Christian may have with jokes and personal stories, in addition to some drinks and food. In the end, Michael is able to sell Christian on the fact that he "knows" Scranton.

So while Michael may be unconventional in many ways, he is capable of coming through when it counts, and I think this is the best explanation of how he became regional manager.

Comment: Absolutely agreed. This made perfect sense as to he being a people person! Thankyou Ryan, hows kelly?

Comment: Haha I see what you did there

Comment: Michael is also a decent manager from time to time (even if only through inaction). E.g. in "Did I Stutter", he managed to find a compromise for Stanley: he's allowed to dislike Michael, but he's not allowed to do so loudly and publically. Although usually done for the surprising effect, there are times where Michael actually manages to do his job quite well. He just has a terrible habit of being easily distracted and blind to awkwardness.

Comment: The best example is probably when he opens Michael Scott Paper Company. Yes, he's offering his services at an unsustainable low price, but it's his interpersonal relationships with the clients that allows him to get them away from Dunder Mifflin.